# Capture (remove) all double-quotes after colon

Tags: regex

I'm trying to clean up a string. An example string:

```
{
    "NodeID":  "${NodeID}",
    "EventID":  "${EventID}"
}
```

I want to capture all double quotes which occur **after** the colon, so that the end string will be:

```
{
    "NodeID":  ${NodeID},
    "EventID":  ${EventID}
}
```

I know that it's JSON, and that technically it is a string in those positions, but they're macros that will be interpreted by a system which generates the actual JSON string and replaces the macros with data, so in my use case this text isn't JSON yet. I can deal with the text line-by-line to make it easier.

I'll be using the regex pattern in both PowerShell and Python.

The closest I've gotten so far have been: `(?<=[^*:])(")`, and `(?<=:)(.*)(?<!,)`

This is working, but seems incredibly kludgy and inelegant:

```
$String = '{
    "NodeID":  "${NodeID}",
    "EventID":  "${EventID}"
}'

#  The Regex to match the text after the colon
[regex]$Regex = '(?<=:)(.*)'

#  Splitting each line of the string into an ArrayList element
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$StringArray = $String.Split([string[]][Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::None)

#  Declaring an output string
$OutPutString = ''

#  Loop through the ArrayList
$i = 1
foreach ($Row in $StringArray) {
    #  Split each element string at the RegEx match
    $RowArray = $Row -split $Regex
    [String]$RowString1 = $RowArray[0]

    [String]$RowString2 = $RowArray[1]
    
    #  Reassemble the element string after replacing the double quotes in the 2nd half
    $FullRowString = $RowString1 + $RowString2.Replace('"','')

    #  If this is the first line in the string, don't add a new line charact in front
    if ($i -gt 1) {
        $NewLine = "`n"
    }

    #  Reassemble the string
    $OutPutString += $NewLine + $FullRowString
    $i++
}

$OutPutString
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Use: `/(?<=:\s*)"([^"]*)"/g` and replace with `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

️ For the regex to be functional as expected, the *regex-engine* indicated by **scripting/programming language** is important to know.
Please always add this information as tags besides [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

Here: [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), [python](/questions/tagged/python)

### Regex to match a JSON text-field and capture the raw-value

Tested on Python, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGwoFj/1):

```py
(?<=:\s\s)\"([^\"]*)\"
```

#### ️ Components

To explain the composition of the regex and its working in steps:

- `(?<=:\s\s)`: *positive look behind* `?<=:` for **2 *white-spaces*** `\s\s`

  to neglect the field-name also enclosed in double-quotes
- `\"` and `\"`: matching **double-quotes** before and after the *capture group*

  the unwanted enclosing of the field-value
- `([^\"]*)`: **capture-group** denoted by *parentheses* surround any *non-double-quote* character `[^\"]*`

  the wanted **raw field-value (string)** without enclosing double-quotes

**ℹ️ Note:**
The character-group `[^\"]` matches any non (`^`) double-quote `\"`.
It will start matching at the leading double-quote and stop matching as soon as a double-quote is detected. So the final `\"` in the regex is optional: It is not required for matching/capturing, but will ensure that each matched field-value is correctly enclosed by double-quotes.

#### Result

Matching following input lines:

```
{
    "NodeID":  "${NodeID}",
    "EventID":  "${EventID}"
}
```

Will give the desired *raw field-values* in **group 1** for each match:

e.g.

- `${NodeID}` for the first match
- `${EventID}` for the second match

### ️ Working with JSON in PowerShell

For your context assumed as parsing JSON following related links may be useful:

- Microsoft Scripting Blog: [Working with JSON data in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/working-with-json-data-in-powershell/)
- Related Question: [PowerShell parsing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945944/powershell-parsing-json)
- PowerShell Explained: [Powershell: The many ways to use regex](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/)